# SQL Format('MMMM') does not work in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I had this query

```
select 
    format([time], 'MMMM') as 'Month', 
    count([time]) as 'Application Usage', 
    count([time]) as 'Application Usage' 
from 
    UserLogs UL 
where 
    [time] >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6, current_timestamp)), 0) 
    and Ul.UserId = @user 
group by
    format([time],'MMMM')
```

However I migrated to a server using SQL Server 2008 and I get this error:

> 'format' is not a recognized built-in function name

What can I use to replace this format function?

Comment: It was introduced in 2012.  Perhaps try  Select datename(MONTH,GetDate())

Comment: Just as a side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Comment: Sometimes, one cannot choose when to upgrade ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a feature with SQL Server 2012 and higher. Try `DATENAME(MONTH,[time]).`

Comment: `select (select datename(month, [time])) as 'Month', count([time]) as 'Application Usage', count([time]) as 'Application Usage' from UserLogs UL
  where [time] >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6,
current_timestamp)), 0)
and Ul.UserId = 1`

gives this error:

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column 'UserLogs.time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @KevoyWalters Did you update the GROUP BY to also be DATENAME(MONTH,[time])?

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server 2008 doesn't support `format()`.  There is sort of a reciprocal relationship here -- Microsoft no longer supports SQL Server 2008.

In any case, just use `datename()`:

```
select datename(month, [time]) as Month
```

Comment: I did this and it works when its byitself but when I put it in a query like this
select (select datename(month, [time])) as 'Month', count([time]) as 'Application Usage', count([time]) as 'Application Usage' from UserLogs UL
  where [time] >= Dateadd(Month, Datediff(Month, 0, DATEADD(m, -6,
current_timestamp)), 0)
and Ul.UserId = 1

It doesnt work

Comment: It says Column 'UserLogs.time' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. and I put a group by and it says i cant use sub query in group by clause

Comment: @unhandledExcepSean

Comment: @KevoyWalters . . . You need a `GROUP BY`.